# How to repeat an array together with a counter

Tags: java

What I’m trying to do with the following code is to print numbers and to replace the number with a word for the number that are divisible for 3, for 5 and for both 3 and 5.
So, when the user starts the code, it has to choose how many players are going to play.

The problem is that my code print all the numbers from 1 to 100 four times, one time for every player.
Can someone kindly explain me where is the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Why have you removed your code completely? The question doesn't make any sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions to that problem.

**Option 1**

In your case, there is no player object needed. So you could make use of a counter. That one will start by 1 and be incremented until it equals the selected number of players. Then you have to reset it to 1 again.

```
    int player = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 3 and 5");
      } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 3");
      } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 5");
      } else {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: " + i);
      }
      if (player < playersNumber) {
        player++;
      } else {
        player = 1;
      }
    }
```

**Option 2**

If you really need a player object, I will advise you to make use of a queue. Also therefore you do not need an extra for-loop.

```
final Queue<Integer> allPlayers = new LinkedList<>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= playersNumber; i++) {
    allPlayers.add(i);
  }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      final int player = allPlayers.poll();
      allPlayers.add(player);
      if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 3 and 5");
      } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 3");
      } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: divisible for 5");
      } else {
        System.out.println("player " + player + " says: " + i);
      }
    }
```

Both solutions are not perfect, but there are working ones.
If something is unclear with these solutions do not hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I can post here a working example, but that will have no learning effect for you. So please answer my question.

What was your intention to use this:

```
        for(int p = 0; p <= 100; p++){
         for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
         }
        }
```

Why do you think, you need two for-loop with each 100 iterations?

Comment: Ok top. Then let's do it step by step. Remove one of them, run the program and look at the result. What do you get?

Comment: Good, for the first step just ignore this var. and put a placeholder in your system output. Something like that: `System.out.println("'player X' says: divisible for 3 and 5");`

Comment: Nice, so for the next step you have to find a solution for the player's number issue. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and don't overcomplicate things without a need. You alredy seem to be familiar with the modulo operator. Just use that to get the current player:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int playersNumber;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of players (min 2, max 6)");
    playersNumber = scanner.nextInt();

    //add so many players as user interd number
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= playersNumber; i++) {
        players.add("Player " + i);
    }

    // use modulo operator to get the current player. 
    // Note: list indexes are zero based, but your player number start with one, 
    // so you need to substract one from i
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println(players.get((i-1) % playersNumber) + " says: divisible for 3 and 5");
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(players.get((i-1) % playersNumber) + " says: divisible for 3");
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println(players.get((i-1) % playersNumber) + " says: divisible for 5");
        } else {
            System.out.println(players.get((i-1) % playersNumber) + " says: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```